# How to embed twitter timeline to Angular4 app

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter

New to Angular, please bear with me. I need to load in tweets from a specific timeline. What is the best way to accomplish this? I've tried using this package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-twitter-timeline), and have followed the instructions in that documentation, but I still get the error that "ng4-twitter-timeline is not a known element."

I've also tried adding in

```
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" async></script>
```

to index.html...

Are there additional scripts that need to be loaded in for this to work?

app.module.ts

```
...
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SwiperModule } from 'angular2-useful-swiper';
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome/angular-font-awesome';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ShareModule } from 'ng2share/share.module';
import { MasonryModule } from 'angular2-masonry';
import { routes } from './app-routing.module';
import { Ng4TwitterTimelineModule } from 'ng4-twitter-timeline/lib/index';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ...
  ],
  imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     HttpModule,
     AngularFontAwesomeModule,
     SwiperModule,
     RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
     ShareModule,
     MasonryModule,
     Ng4TwitterTimelineModule
  ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

tweets.component.ts

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { Ng4TwitterTimelineService } from 'ng4-twitter-timeline/lib/index';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-tweets',
    templateUrl: './tweets.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tweets.component.scss']
  })
  export class TweetsComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private ng4TwitterTimelineService: Ng4TwitterTimelineService) {}

   ngOnInit() {}
}
```

tweets.component.html

```
   <ng4-twitter-timeline [dataSrc]="{sourceType: 'profile',screenName: 'lokers_one'}" [opts]="{tweetLimit: 2}"></ng4-twitter-timeline>
```

Comment: Well that package description is very clear. Without your code we can't tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: Is everything youre doing in the home.component? Did you declare it in your app.module? Importing via <script> tag is a bit different with an angular4 project

Comment: updated the question with my code.

Comment: Do you have any other modules besides app.mod?

Comment: Also remove your <script> tag, it'll cause issues since you imported it with your npm installation

Comment: updated to include all imported modules. I've also removed the script tag from the index.html.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `.forRoot` when you imports Ng4TwitterTimelineModule in @ngModule. So your app.module.ts should look like that:

```
...
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SwiperModule } from 'angular2-useful-swiper';
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome/angular-font-awesome';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ShareModule } from 'ng2share/share.module';
import { MasonryModule } from 'angular2-masonry';
import { routes } from './app-routing.module';
import { Ng4TwitterTimelineModule } from 'ng4-twitter-timeline/lib/index';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ...
  ],
  imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     HttpModule,
     AngularFontAwesomeModule,
     SwiperModule,
     RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
     ShareModule,
     MasonryModule,
     Ng4TwitterTimelineModule.forRoot()
  ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, everyone. The account used in the demo has protected tweets... which is why nothing was embedding... I changed the account and it does work. But still don't understand why I'm still getting this error: 'ng4-twitter-timeline' is not a known element'